# How to get final length of a line in a query?

Tags: sqlite, with-statement

I am just learning SQL and I got a task, that I need to find the final length of a discontinuous line when I have imput such as:

```
start | finish
  0   |   3
  2   |   7
  15  |   17
```

And the correct answer here would be 9, because it spans from 0-3 and then I am suppsed to ignore the parts that are present multiple times so from 3-7(ignoring the two because it is between 0 and 3 already) and 15-17. I am supposed to get this answer solely through an sql query(no functions) and I am unsure of how. I have tried to experiment with some code using with, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to ignore all the multiples properly.
My half-attempt:

```
WITH temp AS(
  SELECT s as l, f as r FROM lines LIMIT 1),
  cte as(
  select s, f from lines where s < (select l from temp) or f > (select r from temp)
  )
 select * from cte
```

This really only gives me all the rows tha are not completly usless and extend the length, but I dont know what to do from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive `CTE` that breaks all the `(start, finish)` intervals to as many *1 unit* length intervals as is the total length of the interval and then count all the distinct intervals:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT start x1, start + 1 x2, finish FROM temp
  WHERE start < finish -- you can omit this if start < finish is always true
  UNION
  SELECT x2, x2 + 1, finish FROM cte
  WHERE x2 + 1 <= finish
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x1) length 
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b95cfcb5d85f9144fd7aee8ddf4dabdb).
Result:

| length |
| --- |
| 9 |

Comment: Thank you kindly, I didn't think of making the recursion that way.